Failed to Create the Configuration Database
I am attempting to create a new Single-Server Farm.  Does anyone know how to resolve the following error?
Failed to create the configuration database.
An exception of type System.ArgumentException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The directory name you entered is invalid. Please enter a new name.
System.ArgumentException: The directory name you entered is invalid.  Please enter a new name.

In the logs, I was not able to find the name of the folder referenced in the error.
However, in the logs I was able to find the name of the Config Database.  Despite the message saying it wasn't created, the Database exists in SQL Server.  However, I check the registry and compared it to a Farm I made a while ago.  On the new Server, a large number of the keys are there: Credentials, FarmAdmin and FarmCredentials.  Though, the Secure key, is missing ConfigDB key.  This is the first place that the name of my Database should be, but isn't.
Full Registry path:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\16.0\Secure\ConfigDB

